# Qt5 call a function in a Python script

Tags: python, qt, qt5

I have a simple Qt5 project with a button and a text field, I did create also a py file in the project to check how to call functions in python files, from Qt.

Although now I am stuck; I have my testcpp.h and testcpp.cpp, where I define a string and a function to print that string; although I am not sure how do I call now the function in the python file, which simply print a string.

I want to call the Qt function, and have it call the function in the python file; how do you do that?

testcpp.h file:

```
#ifndef TESTCPP_H
#define TESTCPP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class testcpp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit testcpp(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString getTest_to_print() const;
    void setTest_to_print(const QString &value);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QString test_to_print;

};

#endif // TESTCPP_H
```

testcpp.cpp file:

```
#include "testcpp.h"

testcpp::testcpp(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString testcpp::getTest_to_print() const
{
    return test_to_print;
}

void testcpp::setTest_to_print(const QString &value)
{
    test_to_print = value;
}

void testcpp::PrintViaPython(QString &test_to_print)
{



}
```

Python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    from PySide import QtWidgets
except:
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class test_python:
    def __init__(self):


    def testme(self, string_to_print):
        print(string_to_print)
```

Comment: read this: http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Spot on; so I need a library to use python. It is interesting that when I create a new file, python is one of the choices; although not sure why, since I need an external library to use a python file. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I think you mean Qt Creator, that you can create a file in an IDE does not imply that you can run it in your application, that library does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot; indeed the IDE is QT Creator. I did assume wrongly, at this point, that if the IDE create a file type, it also support it :) If you add it as response I can mark it as solution.

Comment: I already replied, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any IDE can create any type of file, that does not imply that it can execute, and that is the case of QtCreator.

Answering the background of the problem I recommend using the [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) library, you could do it from scratch through SIP and the python.h library but it is unnecessary if there is a library I suggest.

Comment: BTW is there any gotcha to build PythonQt? I am getting a ton of compile errors on OSX 10.11, in the __locale when running `build all`.

Comment: I have compiled it in linux, not in other OS.